# CodeIgniter works on any virtual hosting service but IPOWER?

Tags: codeigniter

I've been working on a case using Pyrocms, a CI-based CMS, on my local WAMP server for couple months. Recently, I'm starting to deploy on client's webhosting server of IPOWER (www.ipower.com).

The installation process stops after step one. And the error message is below.

ON CHROME

> Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)

I've also tried on IE, Firefox, and they all stops on step one.

So, I've began a LONG investigation, I've found several CodeIgniter-based CMS can NOT work well on IPOWER. They all show the Error 101 in Chrome. That's why I start to wonder is there something wrong on the setting of IPOWER web hosting. Then I've check all the setting, including .htaccess / sessions / rewrite mod...etc, none of them have problem. I don't know if this is another ignorantly frustrating.

Would somebody help me? Or any possible suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you have a look here?

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=476f762a0f84017f&hl=en

Comment: Thanks Phil. Yes, I've read that. However, this's not a browser, cache or win7 problem. I have tried on different PCs, and the results are the same. I've even asked the IPOWER support team to check, and they was able to duplicate the issue in the second step. Unfortunately, they do not assist in installing 3rd party applications.

I tried to follow the code of Pyrocms installer last night. It seems like the problem is occurred when calling "redirect".

redirect('welcome');

Once it was called, Error 101 problem was remained for a period of time. During this time, I can't even run the caller.

Comment: I've just found this. If I delete the cookie in my browser, I can start over immediately. However, this is doing nothing help, but just saving time for testing. Because it, I'm wondering if this is due to the "session / cookie" problems.

Comment: Wouldnt it be easiest to contact IPOWER then?

Comment: Yes, I did. They were able to duplicate the issue in the second step. 
Unfortunately, they do not assist in installing 3rd party applications.

Comment: Can you run it from Wget instead of browser? (see my answer)

Comment: I should have noticed this earlier. The following error log is generated by CodeIgniter.
- - - - - - - - - 
ERROR - 2010-09-26 14:46:56 --> Severity: Notice --> Undefined index: __cache_expires /hermes/bosweb/web007/b76/ipw.usgearco/public_html/application/libraries/Cache.php 240
- - - - - - - - - -
I am making a new request to my web hosting service, I believe this is because the difference of real directory path and symbolic path caused by their shared hosting architecture. I just google this, there're quite a few problem like this, however, none of them got resolved, weird.

Comment: Thanks for everyone helping me here. I will wait iPOWER's feedback and report the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've found the answer. The problem is solved by enable the following setting in config.php. And you need to create a table to hold the sessions as well. I don't understand why this is so. But it totally solves my problem, so I just write down here and hope someone like me could get help by reading this.

> $config['sess_use_database']      = TRUE;
>
> $config['sess_table_name']        =
>   'ci_sessions';

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the cookie settings in the config.php file?

This one:

$config['cookie_domain']    = ".your-domain.com";

Comment: What are your Session Variables settings in config.php? It sounds like it must be something session related to me.

Comment: $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'company_name';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious, and thinking out loud here -- betting it's not on the dev side, actually more suited for ServerFault, being sort of a networking problem?

I say so not to discourage your question, but perhaps help you think outside of the usual suspects.

So this is a stab in the dark, but given that you're firing this off from a browser, I'd guess you could also do it with Wget?

I've run some HTTP requests that are coded properly and as a safeguard should exit after 1000 or so iterations, but for whatever reason they do not (even modifying the FF config for it).

However, running same HTTP request from Wget works like a champ.

From the [Wikipedia entry on Wget:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget)

> Wget has been designed for robustness
>   over slow or unstable network
>   connections. If a download does not
>   complete due to a network problem,
>   Wget will automatically try to
>   continue the download from where it
>   left off, and repeat this until the
>   whole file has been retrieved. It was
>   one of the first clients to make use
>   of the then-new Range HTTP header to
>   support this feature.

What do you think? I don't offer this with conviction, but on a hunch. If I'm wrong, maybe it's a step outside the box, closer to the solution? Good luck fixing it! I'm eager to know what it is.  :)

Comment: Thanks, Chris. You mean to use wget instead of my redirect funciton like this ? exec("wget http:///www.xyz.com/a/b/c");

Comment: Well, I mean to suggest using wget instead of a standard browser to deploy. You're using a browser to deploy, right? I noticed you tried different browsers as part of your troubleshooting. Perhaps a browser change is on the right path, but instead of a "normal" browser, try Wget.exe?